# How to Dock a control in Monodroid?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, dock

I want to dock the image-button (**btn_add**) to bottom of the activity.

I found couple of similar questions on there but they were useless for me.

Because of the way I used Scroll & Linear & Relative layout.
(Actually I can't set a relative-layout as the main layout of my activity as they said)

How can I do it ?
Please help!

My activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Count"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Question Count"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="65.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/txt_totalCount"
                android:text="" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="True Count"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="65.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/txt_trueCount"
                android:text="" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="False Count"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="65.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/txt_falseCount"
                android:text="" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Num"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="65.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/txt_number"
                android:text="" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RadioGroup
            android:gravity="right"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rdoGroup">
            <TextView
                android:text="Has Negative"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Yeah"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/rdo_true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nope"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/rdo_false"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RadioGroup>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Percent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />
            <EditText
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="65.0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:id="@+id/txt_percent"
                android:text="" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/create_icon"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                   
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/btn_add" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why can't you set a relative-layout as the main layout of your activity? There's no fundamental reason preventing this, so it must be application specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the property "FillViewPort" on the scrollview on true. Like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

That should do the trick!